# Python. Нужно вывести список цифр в обратном порядке

Tags: python, python-3.x, коллекции

Даны два целых числа A и B (A < B). Вывести в порядке убывания все целые числа, расположенные между A и B (не включая числа A и B), а также количество N этих чисел.
помогите вывести в обратном порядке

У меня пока вот какой код получился:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
i = int()
for i in range (-b, -(a + 1)): print(-i) print ("Количество чисел в цикле: ", b - a - 1)
```

Comment: Тут не бюро по написанию кода. Попытки решить задачу самостоятельно были? Где результат?

Comment: stackoverflow - Биржа написание ответов на лабораторные :)

Comment: a = int(input())
b = int(input())
i = int()
for i in range (-b, -(a + 1)):
  print(-i)
print ("Количество чисел в цикле: ", b - a - 1)

Comment: решил уже, да и какая разница биржа или нет? забанятб да?

Comment: Да, на этом сайте могут помочь тем, кто и сам старается. Если у вас нет никаких наработок - могут заминусовать вопрос и закрыть его (и через некоторое время если будет ситуация повторяться у вас будет заблокирована возможность задавать вопросы). Поэтому лучше сразу описывайте что у вас уже есть, какие шаги сделаны, в чём конкретно затык - шансы получить помощь будут гораздо выше. И приводите код не в комментариях, а сразу в вопросе.

Comment: @Эникейщик не ваш случаем минус на вопросе? Может снимете - автор вроде как пытался решить задачу (см. его комментарий)

Comment: @Даниил не ваш случаем минус на вопросе? Может снимете - автор вроде как пытался решить задачу (см. его комментарий)

Comment: Убрал, так ведь сразу в вопрос писать нужно‍♂️

Comment: @AK Не мой. Но могу добавить плюс :)

Answer (score 4):

Ну Вы же почти сделали, только range поаккуратнее можно сделать, используя отрицательный шаг

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

for i in range (b - 1, a, -1):
    print(i)

print("Количество чисел в цикле: ", b - a - 1 if b > a + 1 else 0)
                         #или так:  max(0, b - a - 1)
для 1, 5 выдаёт
4
3
2
Количество чисел в цикле:  3
```

Answer (score 2):

Аналогично ответу **MBo**, но через коллекции и функциональную магию:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

items = list(range(b - 1, a, -1))
print('\n'.join(map(str, items)))
print("Количество чисел в цикле:", len(items))
```